# Does Microsoft have a collection of style guidelines for XML?

Tags: c#, xml, coding-style

I am creating websites/application in C#, and in so doing I have to construct web.config's and app.config's in order to hook them up with providers. My development team seems to no be able to agree on XML conventions, so we wanted to know whether Microsoft has published a document with style guides for such a situation.

I have looked into these guides, and none of the answers that I have found seem to quite give Microsoft's official position on XML styling. For your reference, I have included some of the most promising write-ups:

[.NET Style Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  [Contractor's Opinion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/08/12/xml-element-and-attribute-name-guidelines.aspx)   [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030288/are-there-published-style-guidelines-for-c-sharp-xml-documentation)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but xml isn't a Microsoft thing

Comment: What's a style guideline for XML? And what conventions are there for XML?

Comment: @Sayse No, XML is not an Microsoft thing, but oftentimes, Microsoft, Google , and the like will publish their conventions for such things.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was you seemed to be pidgeon holing your question.. the closest you will find is w3c who have a quite complete online documentation on xml

Answer (score 0):

There are some "guidelines" for Xml Schema: [W3C XML Schema Design Patterns: Avoiding Complexity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468564.aspx) , but not for plain XML I believe.

If your talking about .NET .config files, it's a subject in itself. The implicit guideline is camel casing everywhere, matching .NET classes full type name. The fact that the XML is indeed backed by an XML schema is quite a strong guideline for various reasons: validation, and also intellisense (auto completion) support by XML Tools. For Visual Studio, see this here on SO: [How do I get intellisense in app.config for a custom section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378105/how-do-i-get-intellisense-in-app-config-for-a-custom-section)